# Can multiple 802.11n access points increase the amount of android devices capable of connecting to a NAS

Tags: wireless-networking, nas, 802.11n

I am trying to deploy a local wireless server using a synology DS720+ with two 120GB SSD's which can be accessed by anyone on the local network. The office space im deploying to has limited access to high end devices using 802.11/ax or ac Wi-Fi. And therefore most workers would have to utilise mostly outdated Wi-Fi 4 or 802.11/n standards. So far I've tried seeing if atleast 20+ devices can connect to an ASUS business router (Brt-Ac383) but because the devices are Wi-Fi 4 instead of the latest Wi-Fi 6 I can only achieve 2MB of download speed with only 5 devices connected using the SMB protocol enabled by the FileManager+ app found on the play store. Making it impossible to be usable in my target deployment.

All Ethernet cables from the NAS to the Wi-Fi router where all Cat-6 and they were all capable of delivering 1gb throughput connection, so hardware speed isn't the issue, and the bottleneck must definately be the Wi-Fi

I've read that many Ubiquiti access points can help improve Wi-Fi congestion and allow alot more total devices to access the NAS storage.

But will more access points actually help solve the issue of Wi-Fi 4 congestion? Or because all access points technically have the same Gateway back to the main router will it just make the problem worse? All 802.11n devices used were 5ghz capable and access outside the local area network isn't needed as only people within the office will have access to it.

Comment: You need to figure out what the bottleneck is and that will tell you what needs upgrading or replacing. Reading something is not research. So what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: "But will more access points actually help solve the issue of Wi-Fi 4 congestion?" Yes, if you put them on different frequencies, or fine tune coverage. Watch out for the "hidden station" problem. "because all access points technically have the same Gateway back to the main router" your wired backbone and the switch you are using should have the required bandwidth, ofc.

Comment: @music2myear I've tested out the deployment using 802.11ac devices and managed to recieve much faster speeds with exactly the same hardware setup. When switching to 802.11n Wi-Fi only devices even with 5Ghz, I only managed to achieve less than 2mb/s downloads per device with 5 devices connections. Which is far fewer than what is required.

Comment: @dirkt so simply add more access points, with different channels? Most on the files on NAS will be accessed through SMBv2 protocol and not a standard web interface. Is it worth still teasting out?

Comment: SMBv2 or web interface makes no difference. Read up on needed channel separation for 2.4 GHz channels. Make sure to map out (e.g. with a Smartphone app) where channels interfere, adjust signal strength. Make sure to bridge the wired backbone to the WLAN AP.